# FBX 2012 cannot instantiate abstract class

Tags: c++, fbx, virtual-destructor

I'm trying to override the memory allocation for FBS 2012 SDK as its very slow.

Supposedly you create a KFbxMemoryAllocator and pass it your functions

```
// This supposedly overrides the virtual destructor

fbxsdk_2012_2::KFbxMemoryAllocator::~KFbxMemoryAllocator()
{
}

// This creates the SDK Manager

lSdkManager = KFbxSdkManager::Create();

// This creates the allocator class

KFbxMemoryAllocator * allocator=KFbxMemoryAllocator (
MyFbxMallocProc,
MyFbxCallocProc,
MyFbxReallocProc,
MyFbxFreeProc,
MyFbxSizeProc,
MyFbxMallocProc,
MyFbxCallocProc,
MyFbxReallocProc,
MyFbxFreeProc,
MyFbxSizeProc);

// assign the allocator to the sdk manager

lSdkManager->SetMemoryAllocator(allocator);
```

However, I get the error message on compiling

error C2259: 'fbxsdk_2012_2::KFbxMemoryAllocator' : cannot instantiate abstract class
1>        due to following members:
1>        'fbxsdk_2012_2::KFbxMemoryAllocator::~KFbxMemoryAllocator(void)' : is abstract

in the FBX SDK, class KFBX_DLL KFbxMemoryAllocator has the following virtual destructor

```
virtual ~KFbxMemoryAllocator() = 0;
```

I think the error occurs because you cant leave the virtual destructor virtual, but I thought I'd given the destructor above ?

Any idea why it still complains ? Does anyone have any code that works. We can't upgrade to 2015 yet as all our code uses the 2012 format.

thanks

Shaun